# Spinner doesn't show up

Tags: android, android-emulator

I'm currently bereft at the moment. I'm working on an application (Android) using a spinner but "incredible is nothing" it doesn't work at all. I mean, It displays the title but the list of items doesn't show up. It would be really nice if you could give me an explanation. (I'm a newbie in this tech ...). I followed all possible deals but nothing ...

Here is my source (of the activity) :

```
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.form_find_layout);

    /********************** Les composants ********************/
    String[] listLoyer = {"200","250","300","350","400","450","500","550","600","650","700"};
    String[] listType = {"T1", "T2", "T3", "T4"};
   // ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, listLoyer);
    Spinner loyersMin = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.min_spin);
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
            this, R.array.les_prix, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    loyersMin.setAdapter(adapter);
    loyersMin.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter1 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
            this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, listLoyer);
    Spinner loyersMax = ((Spinner) findViewById(R.id.max_spin));
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    loyersMax.setAdapter(adapter1);
    loyersMax.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);


    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter2 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
            this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, listType);
    Spinner type_appart = ((Spinner) findViewById(R.id.type_spin));
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    type_appart.setAdapter(adapter2);
    type_appart.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

    Button loginBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.find_btn);
    loginBtn.setOnClickListener(this);
  }
```

Thanks for all

Comment: Can you post form_find_layout.xml ?

Answer (score 0):

I've solved my trouble. For those who get the same trouble with thier spinner, make sure that your "setContentView" targets the right layout, besides, that you correctly called your activity by the "mother" (or the caller class) activity (in my case).

Hope it helps you!